# Struggling to deploy a React/Flask app to Render. I need to know how to modify my code to deploy successfully

Tags: python, postgresql, docker, flask, deployment

So, I've always deployed applications on Heroku, but the Postgres plugin is no longer free along with pretty much everything else. As an alternative, I've switched to Render.

What I've done.

- Successfully created a local application running a React Frontend and a Flask backend using a local Postgress Database.
- I've made a Database on ElephantSQL and added the `DATABASE_URL` to the environment variables on Render
- I've linked my GitHub repo to Render and ElephantSQL for it to deploy and build whenever I push updates to my master on GitHub

I'm getting an error on my Render log `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'your_application'` making me thing that I've not set something up right in my app.

Docker file:

```
FROM python:latest
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
COPY pgserver.py /server/pgserver.py
EXPOSE 5000
CMD ["gunicorn", "-b", "0.0.0.0:5000", "pgserver:app"]
```

requirements.txt

```
blinker==1.6.2
certifi==2023.5.7
charset-normalizer==3.1.0
click==8.1.3
colorama==0.4.6
Flask==2.2.5
Flask-SQLAlchemy==3.0.3
greenlet==2.0.2
gunicorn==20.1.0
idna==3.4
itsdangerous==2.1.2
Jinja2==3.1.2
MarkupSafe==2.1.2
psycopg2-binary==2.9.6
python-dotenv==0.21.1
requests==2.30.0
SQLAlchemy==2.0.13
typing_extensions==4.5.0
urllib3==2.0.2
Werkzeug==2.2.3
```

pgserver.py

```
import os
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from psycopg2 import connect
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()

# Initialize app
app = Flask(__name__)

# Configure PostgreSQL database connection
db_url = os.environ['DATABASE_URL']
conn = connect(db_url)

# Initialize database
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = db_url
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

# Model
# API Routes

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # get the port number from the PORT environment variable
    port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5000))
    # Log the port number
    print(f"Running on port {port}")
    # run the app on the assigned port
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port)
```

Folder Structure:

```
. root
.. client
.. server
... pgserver.py
. Dockerfile
. requirements.txt
```

I typically build MERN Stacks and this is my first take on using Docker, Python, Flask, Postgres, and deploying on Render. Assume you're talking to someone who knows the bare minimum about those languages, please.

I'd just like to showcase this application as I continue to develop it while learning more about these languages. The repo can be found here: https://github.com/WasteOfADrumBum/react-flask-edu